# Changing Horizontal menu to vertical menu

Tags: css, stylesheet

I here is my code for horizontal menu. Now i want to change this into vertical menu. I am not getting how to do. Please help me how to do it.
I tried changing the width but not happening. I am not getting where to edit `<ul><li>` tags to change it to vertical.
Please suggest me

```css
#menu {
    background: url('../image/menu.png') repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 34px;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    min-width: 900px;
}
#menu > ul.left {
    float: left;
}
#menu > ul.right {
    float: right;
}
#menu > ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu > ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('../image/transparent.png');
}
#menu > ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
#menu > ul > li + li {
    background: url('../image/split.png') center left no-repeat;
}
#menu > ul .top, #menu > ul li li.sfhover {
    padding: 10px 15px 9px 17px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu > ul ul li {
    padding: 2px;
}
#menu > ul .selected .top {
    background: url('../image/selected.png') repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu > ul .selected:hover a.top, #menu > ul .sfhover a.top {
}
#menu > ul .parent {
    background: url('../image/arrow-right.png') 95% center no-repeat;
}
#menu > ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu > ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
#menu > ul li li {
    clear: both;
}
#menu > ul li ul a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 15px;
    width: 145px;
}
#menu > ul li ul ul {
    margin: -27px 0 0 157px;
}
#menu > ul li li:hover, #menu > ul li li.sfhover {
    background: #333;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: @MyHeadHurts ya remove it from #menu > ul li

Comment: I have removed the float , but its not working.

Comment: plz provide html or create jsfiddle

Comment: here is the link for demo. but dont know why its not displaying
http://jsfiddle.net/prasanna123/H3Um4/

Comment: You styled your anchors with #FFF, no wonder they don't show up, also you hid your .left with display: none; I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H3Um4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the

```
min-width: 900px;
```

in

```
#menu
```

causes your navigation to stay in a horizontal rectangle. It seems like your trying to make your site responsive? Perhaps set a desirable **max-width** and have your your li elements have a width of 100%

Comment: -1 the min-width has no connection why the menu stays in horizontal position.

Comment: hmm ... perhaps i'm misinterpreting the question, but it seems like Nikola wants it to be a vertical sidebar and not a horizontal menu?
Dexter, looking at your jsbin, changing min-width to max-width: 100px; for example begins the workings of a vertical menu

Comment: No, i have changed min ti max and li to 100%, still its not a vertical menu

Comment: Hey Prasanna,
Just to clarify for the first <ul></ul>, did you just want to float the ul and not the children <li></li>

What's happening is that your child list elements are inheriting float:left from #menu > ul.left

You need to disable it with
#menu ul.left li {
    float: none;
}
see sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/radialglo/GpKFx/

Comment: Yup! I got it resolved. Thanks a lot. I have removed float and adjusted the min-width 900 to desirable width. But now my client is asking me to put accordion there :(. I am raising one more ticket for that. Thanks to all.